Azure EchoBot not sending any messages. No greeting and no answers
I created a minimal setup of Azure EchoBot. My solution includes an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and an Angular app. I followed the template for the EchoBot and deployed it to an Azure app service /linux/.
The Angular app has the WebChat control installed and I am able to send messages, which show up in the chat. However the bot is not returning any answers or sending a greeting when first opened.
Here is a screenshot of the developer console in Chrome:

Here is my EchoBot class:
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;

namespace limbo.dating.Server.Bots
{
    public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Log the activity type
            Console.WriteLine($"Activity Type: {turnContext.Activity.Type}");

            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var replyText = $"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}";
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(replyText, replyText), cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var welcomeText = "Hello and welcome!";

            // Log the number of members added
            Console.WriteLine($"Members added count: {membersAdded.Count}");

            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                // Log each member added
                Console.WriteLine($"Member added: {member.Id}");

                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(welcomeText, welcomeText), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is the configuration in Program.cs:
using limbo.dating.Server.Bots;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowedCorsOrigins",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            //.AllowCredentials();
        });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

// Create the Bot Framework Authentication to be used with the Bot Adapter.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<BotFrameworkAuthentication, ConfigurationBotFrameworkAuthentication>();

// Create the Bot Adapter with error handling enabled.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

// Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
builder.Services.AddTransient<IBot, limbo.dating.Server.Bots.EchoBot>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseRouting();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();

Appsettings.json:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<mydomain>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<mytenantid>",
    "ClientId": "<myclientid>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftAppType": "MultiTenant",
    "MicrosoftAppId": "<mymicrosoftappid>",
    "MicrosoftAppPassword": "mymicrosoftapppassword",
    "MicrosoftAppTenantId": ""
}

In the Angular app, I have the following for app.component.ts:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as BotChat from "botframework-webchat";
import { createDirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';
import { TokenService } from './services/token.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] // Corrected property name
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  @ViewChild('botWindow')
  botWindowElement!: ElementRef;

  token!: string;

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Fetch the token when the component initializes
    this.tokenService.getDirectLineToken().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.token = data.token; // Assign the token
        console.log('Token fetched:', this.token);
        this.initializeWebChat(); // Initialize WebChat after token is fetched
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching token:', error);
      }
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Initialization moved to initializeWebChat method
  }

  initializeWebChat(): void {
    const directLine = createDirectLine({
      token: this.token
    });

    interface Action {
      type: string;
      payload?: any;
    }

    interface StoreAPI {
      dispatch: (action: Action) => void;
    }

    const store = BotChat.createStore({},
      (storeAPI: StoreAPI) => (next: (action: Action) => void) => (action: Action) => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        storeAPI.dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'webchat/join',
            value: { language: window.navigator.language }
          }
        });
      }
      return next(action);
    });

    BotChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: directLine,
      store: store,
      userID: 'support@limbo.dating',
      botID: 'limbo-dating-bot',
      withCredential: true,
    }, this.botWindowElement.nativeElement);

    directLine.connectionStatus$.subscribe(status => {
      if (status === 2) {
        console.log('DirectLine connected');
      } else if (status === 4) {
        console.error('DirectLine connection failed');
      }
    });

    directLine.connectionStatus$.subscribe(status => {
      if (status === 2) {
        console.log('DirectLine connected');

        // Send a test message to the bot
        directLine.postActivity({
          from: { id: 'support@limbo.dating', name: 'User' },
          type: 'message',
          text: 'Hello, bot!'
        }).subscribe(
          id => console.log('Message sent, activity id:', id),
          error => console.error('Error sending message:', error)
        );
      } else if (status === 4) {
        console.error('DirectLine connection failed');
      }
    });

    directLine.activity$.subscribe(activity => {
      if (activity.from.id !== 'support@limbo.dating') {
        console.log('Incoming message:', activity);
      } else {
        console.log('Outgoing message:', activity);
      }
    });
  }
}

I expect the EchoBot to reply with "Echo: " + whatever I typed in the chat window.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Opening https://limbo-dating-server-app-service.azurewebsites.net/api/messages results in a 500 error.

please check the configuration of your application.

Something more specific? I am getting a directLine token.

I can able to connect my bot application to my azure bot service by configuring endpoint url of my app service

Karlsson, please check deployment status, endpoint configuration, Test in webchat.

have you checked Log Stream or Application Insights for the App Service (limbo-dating-server-app-service)?

Confirm that Angular app sends messages correctly to /api/messages.


browser console: (Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response...)

The bot's endpoint /api/messages might not be responding correctly or the connection is being closed prematurely this is the only cause for the above error.
Test the endpoint URL by making a POST request to
https://limbo-dating-server-app-service.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

JSON body:
{
  "type": "message",
  "from": {
    "id": "test-user"
  },
  "text": "Hello, bot!"
}

Set the headers:

 Authorization: Bearer <DirectLineToken>
Content-Type: application/json.

In the Azure Bot Service, confirm the Messaging endpoint is like

Update the custom adapter (AdapterWithErrorHandler) to log more details about errors.
public class AdapterWithErrorHandler : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
{
    public AdapterWithErrorHandler(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger)
        : base(configuration, logger)
    {
        OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
        {
            logger.LogError(exception, "Unhandled error: {Message}", exception.Message);
            
            // Send error message to user
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, something went wrong.");
        };
    }
}


Monitor the activity$ observable to confirm if activities are received from the bot:

directLine.activity$.subscribe(activity => {
  console.log('Activity received from bot:', activity);
});

Deployed the application to app service.

Tested:

Before running the application test the endpoint url - /api/messages using postman or curl.

Thank you for your answer! I tested the /api/messages endpoint in Postman and it returns a login page.

are you using AAD?

Direct Line requests do not use AAD tokens—they use their own bearer token for authorization.

Direct Line requests to /api/messages will include a Bearer token issued by Direct Line. Your bot should validate this token, not AAD tokens.

Yes, I believe I am using Microsoft Entra ID. How do I turn it off?

Navigate to the app services resource, under the Settings section, click Authentication you’ll see App Service Authentication: On. Turn it off

That page shows 'Add identity provider'. In 'Identity' I turned of the System assigned one.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
